# Array removing duplicate entries where they exceed an X value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

PHP
I have two single-arrays that are populated from two tables, with IDs. From one array I need to be able to remove all ID's of the same value where there are more than X number appearing.
I am doing this:

```
volunteerRoleQuery = mysql_query("SELECT member_no, role_code, volunteer_date FROM         evntrole WHERE volunteer_date > '$today' ");
$numberEvntRole = mysql_numrows($volunteerRoleQuery);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($volunteerRoleQuery)) {
    $member_no = $row["member_no"];
    array_push($volunteersArray, $member_no);
}

fputcsv($output, array('Member number', 'Full name', 'First name', 'Surname', 'Email', 'Mobile', 'Phone'));

$teamMemQuery = mysql_query("SELECT member_number, activity_code, modify_date FROM  teammem WHERE modify_date > '$today' ");
    $numberTeamMem = mysql_numrows($teamMemQuery);

if ($numberTeamMem > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($teamMemQuery)) {
        $member_no = $row["member_number"];
        array_push($teamMemArray, $member_no);        
    }
}
```

//todo: only keep member ID's with more than x events, say 3 
//      eg 1,1,2,3,3,3,3,6,7,7,7,7 will keep only 3,7
//      This ensures we do not ask members to volunteer if only done a few events.

```
$result=array_unique($teamMemArray);

array_diff_ORG_NEW($teamMemArray,$volunteersArray, 'VALUES');

$result=array_unique($teamMemArray);
sort($result);
foreach ($result as &$value) {
        $resultNames = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, surname, mobile, phone_home, e_mail  FROM names WHERE member_no='$value'");
        $rowNames = mysql_fetch_array($resultNames);
        $firstName = $rowNames['first_name'];
        $surname = $rowNames['surname'];

            if ($surname > "") {
                fputcsv($output, array($value, $names, $firstName, $surname, $email, $mobile, $homePhone));
        }
}
```

Comment: The array may look like:
1,1,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,etc If the X value is 3 then only 7 will remain.
Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly what you need but, have you looked into: 
[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) from PHP?

It gives you another array with how many matches it found for a keyword.

You could just loop through it and delete any keys with results greater then X?

Comment: The overall task is to compare those people who have volunteered over a given time period with how many events they have done. There are 2 variables: The number of events done and the number of years to look back.

Comment: Anyone have any example code to remove all the values unless they meet the criteria shown above.

Comment: I am sorry, you neither explain properly or show enough code for me to understand exactly what you need.  
Please edit your question, and add concise information and I will help you.